# Syntax for HTML data attributes?

Tags: custom-data-attribute

My experience with HTML data attributes is mostly when using bootstrap and some other jQuery plugins, whereby the data attribute in the markup is looks something like:

```
<button id="dLabel" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown">Trigger</button>
```

where the syntax is `data-*`. So to target the element I would use something like `$('button[data-toggle])`.

However, I recently come across some code (which works perfectly) where the syntax looks like:

```
<option data:slot="0" data:session="7.30am to 2.00pm">Early session</option>
```

Why does the code work even though it doesn't use the `data-*` syntax? I'm sure I'm missing something here.